# Webcam install makes Pi unbootable

Tags: boot-issues, webcam

I just tried to install an old USB webcam on my Pi 3B and apart from not working, it has stopped the Pi booting (even with webcam removed).
The Pi attempts to boot but fails and does a register dump then tries again after about 20 seconds - continually.
Of course I did not have a recent backup of the Pi (running OctoPi for 3D printing) and I am wondering if there is a way I can access the SD card in another Pi to remove the changes made by the driver install for this webcam. Not sure where to look.
Raspbian/PiOS was recently updated.
I can of course do a fresh install but would prefer to avoid the effort if possible.
Suggestions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how the installation process looked like. If you just ran a binary blob, analyzing its actions might take more time than reinstalling. If it was a human-readable installation script (`install.sh`, `make install`, etc.), you could read it and reverse actions of the installation commands one by one. It could still take a long time, and if the installation script overwrites existing files, you'll have to restore these, e.g. by reinstalling affected packages.

If the installation was done by the package manager, you can mount the SD card on any Linux machine with `apt-get` and remove that package with

```
apt-get -o RootDir=/media/user/pi_sd_card_root/ remove <package>
```

or

```
chroot /media/user/pi_sd_card_root/
apt-get remove <package>
```

This method also applies to the case when the installation script overwrote files owned by other packages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dimitry. I just plugged the camera in and rebooted and it seemed to install drivers automatically. I think you are right - I just need to bite the bullet :-(

Comment: @DavidG I've never seen this ("install drivers automatically") happen in Linux. If the driver was already there, it could have been automatically loaded into the kernel by `udev` service, but that is only effective until a reboot. It could be that something unrelated happened at just the wrong moment: file system error, SD card going end-of-life, or even hardware damage in the Pi itself (from ESD for instance).

Comment: @Dimitry Grigoryev Yes i wondered about the auto install. I might have just seen 'USB Camera' mentioned as it was booting and assumed that is what had happened. Anyway, several hours later, I have it all rebuilt.  Now to get serious about backing up!